# Is there a keyboard shortcut to duplicate a line in gedit?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit, text-editor

Is there a way to duplicate current line in gedit using a keyboard shortcut?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
gedit version: 3.36.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as what I searched, there is no official keyboard shortcut for duplicating a current line in gedit.

Refer this link for more information: https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en

Answer (score 12):

There actually is a 3rd party gedit plugin (compatible with gedit version >= 3.14) that adds a keyboard shortcut to duplicate the current line or selection. Here is how to install and enable it:

1. Download and extract the zip file containing the plugin from this GitHub repository: https://github.com/hannenz/duplicate

   Alternatively you can use `git` (first install it by running `sudo apt install git`) to download it in `~/duplicate` folder using:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/hannenz/duplicate.git ~/duplicate
   ```
2. Copy the contents of the extracted or cloned (depending on how you downloaded) folder (`duplicateline.plugin` and `duplicateline.py`) to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`. If the folder does not exist, create it using your file manager or by running:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
   ```
3. Then open gedit → click the hamburger menu (the icon with the three lines on the top right) → *Preferences* → *Plugins* and check *Duplicate Line*.

   [image: gedit Preferences]
4. You can now use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut to duplicate the current line or selection.

To uninstall the plugin follow step 3 and uncheck *Duplicate Line* and also delete the files `duplicateline.plugin` and  `duplicateline.py` from `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`.